# Rails: link_to and session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create simple CRUD in my web.

index.html.erb

```
 <% @diots.each do |diot| %>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><%= diot.id %></td>
        <td align="center"><%= image_tag(diot.something, width: '50', height: '50') %></td>
        <td align="center"><%= link_to session[:is_checked] ? "Running" : "Stop", (session[:is_checked] ? drive_diot_path(diot) : drive_stop_diot_path(diot)) %></td>
        <td align="center"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_diot_path(diot) %></td>
        <td align="center"><%= link_to 'Destroy', diot, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

When I click one of the "Running", will go drive.html.erb, but I go back index.html.erb, they all change "Stop".

How can I do when I click one of the "Running", back index.html.erb, only the one change to "Stop"?

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed thru documentation or its example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by storing a value in the session for each `diot`:

session[:"is_checked#{diot.id}"]

Giving you: (Note that `:"string"` gives a valid symbol)

```
<% @diots.each do |diot| %>
   <tr>
     <td align="center"><%= diot.id %></td>
     <td align="center"><%= image_tag(diot.something, width: '50', height: '50') %></td>
     <td align="center"><%= link_to session[:"is_checked#{diot.id}"] ? "Running" : "Stop", (session[:"is_checked#{diot.id}"] ? drive_diot_path(diot) : drive_stop_diot_path(diot)) %></td>
     <td align="center"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_diot_path(diot) %></td>
     <td align="center"><%= link_to 'Destroy', diot, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know, I used you suggest, but all change "Stop", can you detailed description? thank you!!

Comment: You'll need to set `session[:"is_checked#{diot.id}"]` to true/ false in the action that is called when they click the link. Otherwise they will be set as `nil` by default and will show `"Stop"`.

Comment: Yes, in the drive action, I set session[:"is_checked#{Diot.find(params[:id])}"] = false, in the drive_stop action, I set session[:"is_checked#{Diot.find(params[:id])}"] = true, but also show "Stop".

Comment: Both of those code snippets in the action should be `session[:"is_checked#{params[:id]}"]` *not* `session[:"is_checked#{Diot.find(params[:id])}"]`